# New column in pandas dataframe based on existing column values with conditions list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following this link: 
[New column in pandas dataframe based on existing column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189392/new-column-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-existing-column-values)

I have a data frame with a column called 'Country' that lists several countries in the world. I need to create another column with a region specifier like 'Europe'. I have three lists of countries that belong to several regions, so if the state in df ['Country'] matches a state in the 'Europe' list, the 'Europe' specifier is inserted in the new column df[' Region'].

my data is:
https://sendeyo.com/up/d/2acd2eb849

The problem is that when I use the solutions expressed in the previous link, they work for the sample dataframes, but not for my database.
my dataframe like this:

```
Year    Country Population  GDP 
1870    Austria  4,520     8,419    
1870    Belgium  5,096     13,716   
1870    Denmark  1,888     3,782    
1870    Finland  1,754     1,999    
1870    France   38,440    72,100
```

My lists:

```
Europa = ["Austria", "Belgium", "Denmark"]

RamasOccidentales = ["Australia","New Zealand","Canada","United States"]

Latinoamerica = ["Brazil","Chile","Uruguay"]

Asia = ["Indonesia","Japan","Sri Lanka"]
```

The expected result

```
Year    Country Population  GDP Region
1870    Austria 4,520   8,419   Europa 
1870    Belgium 5,096   13,716  Europa 
1870    Denmark 1,888   3,782   Europa 
1870    Finland 1,754   1,999   Europa 
1870    France  38,440  72,100  Europa
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
def Continent(country):
    return "Europa" if country in Europa else "Unknown"

df['Region'] = df['Country'].apply(Continent)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried and the output it produced?

Comment: def Continent(country):
    return "Europa" if country in Europa else "Unknown"

df['Region'] = df['Country'].apply(Continent)

Comment: You may need to strip the trailing whitespaces.  `df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.strip()` before you apply the mapping.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary created from lists:

```
Europa = ["Austria", "Belgium", "Denmark",'France','Finland']
RamasOccidentales = ["Australia","New Zealand","Canada","United States"]
Latinoamerica = ["Brazil","Chile","Uruguay"]
Asia = ["Indonesia","Japan","Sri Lanka"]

d = {'Europa':Europa,'RamasOccidentales':RamasOccidentales,
     'Latinoamerica':Latinoamerica,'Asia':Asia}

#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}

df['Region'] = df['Country'].map(d1)

print (df)
   Year  Country Population     GDP  Region
0  1870  Austria      4,520   8,419  Europa
1  1870  Belgium      5,096  13,716  Europa
2  1870  Denmark      1,888   3,782  Europa
3  1870  Finland      1,754   1,999  Europa
4  1870   France     38,440  72,100  Europa
```

---

```
print (d1)

{'Austria': 'Europa', 'Belgium': 'Europa', 'Denmark': 'Europa', 
 'France': 'Europa', 'Finland': 'Europa', 
 'Australia': 'RamasOccidentales', 
 'New Zealand': 'RamasOccidentales', 
 'Canada': 'RamasOccidentales', 
 'United States': 'RamasOccidentales', 
 'Brazil': 'Latinoamerica', 'Chile': 'Latinoamerica', 
 'Uruguay': 'Latinoamerica', 'Indonesia': 'Asia',
 'Japan': 'Asia', 'Sri Lanka': 'Asia'}
```

Performance is for 10k rows 2.58 times better:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

Europa = ["Austria", "Belgium", "Denmark",'France','Finland']
RamasOccidentales = ["Australia","New Zealand","Canada","United States"]
Latinoamerica = ["Brazil","Chile","Uruguay"]
Asia = ["Indonesia","Japan","Sri Lanka"]

d = {'Europa':Europa,'RamasOccidentales':RamasOccidentales,
     'Latinoamerica':Latinoamerica,'Asia':Asia}

d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': np.random.choice(list(d1.keys()), size=10000)})
```

---

```
In [280]: %%timeit
     ...: d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
     ...: 
     ...: df['Region'] = df['Country'].map(d1)
     ...: 
3.04 ms ± 43.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
In [281]: %%timeit
     ...: classification_countries={'Europa':Europa,
     ...:                           'RamasOccidentales':RamasOccidentales,
     ...:                           'Latinoamerica':Latinoamerica ,
     ...:                           'Asia':Asia}
     ...: 
     ...: cond=[df['Country'].isin(classification_countries[key]) for key in classification_countries]
     ...: values=[ key for key in classification_countries]
     ...: 
     ...: df['Region']=np.select(cond,values)
     ...: 
7.86 ms ± 56.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [282]: %%timeit
     ...: cond=[df['Country'].isin(Europa),df['Country'].isin(RamasOccidentales),df['Country'].isin(Latinoamerica),df['Country'].isin(Asia)]
     ...: values=['Europa','RamasOccidentales','Latinoamerica','Asia']
     ...: df['Region']=np.select(cond,values)
     ...: 
7.96 ms ± 281 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [293]: %%timeit
     ...: classification_countries={'Europa':Europa,
     ...:                           'RamasOccidentales':RamasOccidentales,
     ...:                           'Latinoamerica':Latinoamerica ,
     ...:                           'Asia':Asia}
     ...: 
     ...: dict_cond_values= {key:df['Country'].isin(classification_countries[key]) for key in classification_countries}
     ...: 
     ...: 
     ...: df['Region']=np.select(dict_cond_values.values(),dict_cond_values.keys())
     ...: 
8.54 ms ± 1.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) + [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
Europa = ["Austria", "Belgium", "Denmark",'France','Finland']

RamasOccidentales = ["Australia","New Zealand","Canada","United States"]

Latinoamerica = ["Brazil","Chile","Uruguay"]

Asia = ["Indonesia","Japan","Sri Lanka"]


#using np.select
cond=[df['Country'].isin(Europa),df['Country'].isin(RamasOccidentales),df['Country'].isin(Latinoamerica),df['Country'].isin(Asia)]
values=['Europa','RamasOccidentales','Latinoamerica','Asia']
df['Region']=np.select(cond,values)

print(df)
```

---

```
   Year  Country Population     GDP  Region
0  1870  Austria      4,520   8,419  Europa
1  1870  Belgium      5,096  13,716  Europa
2  1870  Denmark      1,888   3,782  Europa
3  1870  Finland      1,754   1,999  Europa
4  1870   France     38,440  72,100  Europa
```

---

**Also you can use a dict to create list of cond and values.It is faster**:

```
classification_countries={'Europa':Europa,
                          'RamasOccidentales':RamasOccidentales,
                          'Latinoamerica':Latinoamerica ,
                          'Asia':Asia}

dict_cond_values= {key:df['Country'].isin(classification_countries[key]) for key in classification_countries}


df['Region']=np.select(dict_cond_values.values(),dict_cond_values.keys())
print(df)
   Year  Country Population     GDP  Region
0  1870  Austria      4,520   8,419  Europa
1  1870  Belgium      5,096  13,716  Europa
2  1870  Denmark      1,888   3,782  Europa
3  1870  Finland      1,754   1,999  Europa
4  1870   France     38,440  72,100  Europa
```

---

or

```
classification_countries={'Europa':Europa,
                          'RamasOccidentales':RamasOccidentales,
                          'Latinoamerica':Latinoamerica ,
                          'Asia':Asia}

cond=[df['Country'].isin(classification_countries[key]) for key in classification_countries]
values=[ key for key in classification_countries]

df['Region']=np.select(cond,values)
print(df)

   Year  Country Population     GDP  Region
0  1870  Austria      4,520   8,419  Europa
1  1870  Belgium      5,096  13,716  Europa
2  1870  Denmark      1,888   3,782  Europa
3  1870  Finland      1,754   1,999  Europa
4  1870   France     38,440  72,100  Europa
```

---

> **comparison with the solution of jezrael measuring after the creation of the dictionary until the execution of print (df)**

```
%%timeit
dict_cond_values= {key:df['Country'].isin(classification_countries[key]) for key in classification_countries}   
df['Region']=np.select(dict_cond_values.values(),dict_cond_values.keys())
print(df)
#5.06 ms ± 215 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
cond=[df['Country'].isin(classification_countries[key]) for key in classification_countries]
values=[ key for key in classification_countries]

df['Region']=np.select(cond,values)
print(df)
#5.18 ms ± 652 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**@jezrael**

```
%%timeit

d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}

df['Region'] = df['Country'].map(d1)

print (df)
#7.88 ms ± 824 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very similar but alternate approach would be to use a dictionary-based lookup to determine the country. In this implementation, you would create a single dictionary with countries as keys and their corresponding region as the paired values.

```
region_map = {
    'Austria': 'Europa',
    'Brazil': 'Latinoamerica',
    'Japan': 'Asia'  # so on and so forth
}
df['Region'] = df['Country'].apply(lambda c: region_map.get(c, 'Unknown'))
```

This will produce either the corresponding country from your dictionary map or the string 'Unknown' if no key-value pair exists.

Comment: So you need a number of keys equal to the number of countries in the world?

Comment: @ansev, yes. In that regard, this approach only works when there is a known, relatively small number of possible values (like countries in the world). It makes the tradeoff of redundancy for improved readability (i.e. avoiding things like cascading `.isin()` method calls).